# Calculate how much a text has changed?

Tags: algorithm, text, compare

How can i calculate how much a text has changed?

For example the following text:

```
1. this is a test
```

Compared to

```
2. this is a testx
```

The change here is very small (addition of x at the end)

The following change is big:

```
1. this is a test
2. this is a test with more text
```

(here i added 'with more text')

I thought of measuring string length and use that to calculate a change percentage. But this approach goes bad in the following case:

```
1. this is a test
2. and i rewrite
```

(almost the same length, but totally different text)

I suspect many people bumped into this problem. But i can't seem to find much on google, likely caused by not knowing what the technology is named that can measure a change in text.

Comment: you are looking for the Levenshtein distance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Levenshtein Distance Metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to see how much the strings differ from each other, the higher the value, the more different the strings are.

There are other [string comparison metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) you can take a look at as well.

Comment: Cheers npinti! Levenshtein distance does exactly what i wanted, great find. Here are some implementations i found: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance . Going to take a look at the string comparison functions you also mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language, but java and python both have pretty good string comparative functions so you would just need to write up a specific algorithm and use some looping to create a degree of error, or change.